# Slot implementation of LRU cache

Tags: data-structures, hash-tables, linked-lists

Usually LRU cache is implemented with double linked list to fast remove oldest visited, push to front, and move from any place to front; also uses map to fast find element by key.
In 64bit systems pointers are wide, and cache has large overhead, especially if key is long and value short. I have tested in C++ with key and value int, cache<int,int> for 10 millions elements, total memory was 72 byte per element, cache<int64_t, int> even 87 bytes, and extremely small size of values cache<int64_t, char> 81 bytes.

I think about slots in preallocated memory; instead of 64 bit pointers, only 32 bit indices to next and previous slot.

Two simplifications:

- elements have equal size
- only add new elements, not remove, count increased to maximal and still maximal

Probably this enable simple “allocation” new elements by increase of buffer position.

Next is map without allocation memory.
Key will hashed (for example by murmur) , this hash modulo number entries give my entry index.
This entry can be already taken, if we would use memory allocation, this new element will point to previous element in this entry, but we haven’t memory allocation, previous element must be moved to another entry, where? How algorithm use?

### My solution

Least Recently Used cache has three main operations:

- put new element on top of list
- remove element from end of list (if elements reaches limit)
- operation get() moves element from any place of list to the beginning of list

First operation can be available in any forward list, but with second, list must be doubly linked.
Third operation requires random seek to any place of list. Must be implemented with map
(map can be unordered). Map has key which is cache key, and value that is doubly linked list iterator.

This has large memory overhead. The list is doubly linked, while in 64bit systems, pointers are
wide.
classic LRU cache uses near 76 bytes/element for cache<int,int>.
It too much, especially if values stored in cache are small.

We can discard completely list, leaving only map.
The unordered_map<in,int> has memory requirement near 44 bytes/element.
This costs somme fuzzing of cache expectations.
We have planar cache with map for new and old elements. If map for new elements will fill up,
we leave old map, new map becomes old and init empty new map.
This guarantee keep N elements in cache and not guarantee up to 2N.
More predictable is to have more maps, for example 4 or 6, but the more maps, the more time
for get old elements, while get new elements still fast. Number of planes will be parameter.
Since 64 bit of pointers is too much, next proposal is resignation from pointers and
instead of this use index in one large array.

```cpp
struct Slot {
    K key;
    V value;
    slot_t next;
};
```

In order not to waste space on the field indicating that the slot is in use,
we use bitmap.
What if the slot is occupied? Usually, in memory hash maps, we will store
new pair<key, value> on top singly linked list (obviously still other operations like check
if key is in this list). Here we must search next empty slot and in first slot we set 'next'
field points to next field.
Erasing is problematic, because one slot can belong to
muliple lists. Instead of erasing is set bit "erased' in another bitmap,
and slot is busy until map garbage collector rewrite buffer to
new buffer the same size or greater size.
Planar cache don't need erase single elements, instead of this release
whole old map.
This way slot map<int,int> uses only 12.25 bytes per element,
(0.25 = 2 bits of two bitmaps)

Comment: This sounds likely to depend on the exact parameters (size of each cache slot, number of elements in the cache) and on the workload.  I'm not sure you're going to find a single simple answer.  You can consider an array / circular buffer as another candidate.

Comment: Remember that LRU is itself a heuristic, and so real-world high-performance (especially concurrent) realisations are often approximate. Truly hot entries ideally shouldn't be moved at all, even to the head of a LRU list.